# "Since leaving" vs "since he left" vs "since he has left"

Tags: meaning, sentence-construction, sentence-structure

What's the difference in meaning of the following sentences:

> 1. Since **leaving** school, he has had three jobs
> 2. Since **he has left** school, he has had three jobs.
> 3. Since **he left** school, he has had three jobs.

Do they mean the same thing, but they are different in terms of sentence structure?

Answer (score 1):

They mean the same thing, but it may surprise you that #1 is better stylistically.

Note that #2 repeats the subject (*he*), which is a redundancy, and the way you have written it it also repeats the present perfect construction (*he has left*, *he has had*).

Note that if you were really going to use #2 you should use simple past in the first clause: "Since he left school, he has had three jobs."

There's a problem with that as well, though: *since* can mean *because*, so the sentence could be interpreted as meaning that he has had three jobs precisely *because* he left school. That ambiguity is also avoided in example #1.